# Python, Dash: how to add a KPI Card component to a dashboard

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash

I'm new to Dash and I'm looking for a component (dash_core_component) to create a KPI card where I can display a single value and a brief description.

Here an example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a dash_core_component but you could use [Cards from the bootstrap dash components](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/l/components/card) to create something like this:

[image]

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html

card = dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardHeader("Marketing"),
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H4("201 new Leads", className="card-title"),
                html.P("Delivered this week compared...", className="card-text"),
            ]
        ),
    ],
    style={"width": "30rem"},
)
```

Add to your css file:

```
.card-text {
  color: #999999;
  margin-bottom: 7.5px;
  display: block;
}

.card-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 7.5px;
}
```

Comment: Cards are now depreciated.  Instead, use bootstrap grids .

Answer (score 1):

Also, plotly has gauge type indicator charts: https://plotly.com/python/indicator/